# Set Local GraalVM JDK in Spring Boot Native

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Whenever i run the gradle task **bootBuildImage**, GraalVM JDK is downloaded for every new project as the console states below:

> Downloading from
> https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-21.1.0/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-21.1.0.tar.gz

How can i set an offline GraalVM JDK for every new project?

Comment: Any update on this? I am getting same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use「SDKMAN」to resolve your question.
Command is:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.0.r8-grl
```

The SDKMAN is a command tool to switch the java enviroment.